# Is using videojs with HLS Aes encryption for commercial video platform make sense?

Tags: encryption, aes, video.js

With all the browser support issues we still have today, do you think it makes sense to use an open source lib, videojs in this case for commercial video platform. This includes a case where all videos will be converted to HLS Aes encryption for content protection, html 5 will be used with flash fallback for some browsers those do not support html 5 hls. My question is, would it be reliable to go with videojs, or should I be choosing something enterprise level like jwplayer or a like? Main concern is hls encryption and browser support.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what player you use if it supports AES-128. However, only AES-128 cannot provide enough security with open source or enterprise level players because when transferring video to user, also the unencrypted key is sent to user. Thus, user can decrypt video and publish it. To prevent this, it is important to use DRM solution. Yet, it is too expensive for an individual web admin. I am a co-founder of a IFE company and of course we prefer to use DRM solution.